# Will I be allowed into Thailand with less than six months on my New Zealand passport?

Tags: passports, thailand, new-zealand-citizens

Will I be allowed into Thailand with less than six months on my New Zealand passport?

Answer (score 5):

[timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=NZ&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=TH&user=EK&subuser=EMIRATES) has (re Thailand):

> - Passports issued to nationals of New Zealand must be valid
>
>   for the period of intended stay.
>
>   - for holders of normal passports;
>   - Emergency and temporary passports issued to nationals of New Zealand must be valid for at least 6 months from date of arrival.

So I think your answer is "Yes", unless your passport is a temporary or emergency one or you are planning on a visit that is longer than the period between your proposed time of entry and your passport's expiry, and subject of course to the usual caveat that almost anyone *might* be refused entry for almost any reason.

The above assumes you do not need a visa. If you do need a visa then you do need [at least six months](http://www.thaiembassyuk.org.uk/?q=node/60) remaining validity for your passport.

Answer (score 0):

To enter Thailand, a passport valid for six months is required by all nationals referred to in the chart above.

Source: http://www.worldtravelguide.net/thailand/passport-visa